# show payment details by default with paypal adaptive payments

Tags: php, javascript, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm currently using paypal adaptive payments and setting up a parallel payment, and using a call to SetPaymentOptions to set up a breakdown of the fees.  What I currently get in the "You are about to pay" screen is the list of receivers with plus buttons next to them and then if you click the plus button it gives you a breakdown of fees.  The problem is that I would like the breakdown of fees lists to start open.  Is this possible?  It seems to be possible using paypal express.
The reason I don't want to just list those fees on my web site is in addition to our extra fees, we are making the customer pay paypal's fee.  I don't want to separate screens where additional fees are tacked on.
Also this one seems more hopeless, but is there any way to get Paypal to call the "Fee" a "Paypal Fee"?

Answer (score 2):

There are two checkout flows.

What you are seeing is the "Classic Flow". For Adaptive Payments it **does not** show the individual line item options set by the SetPaymentOptions API call.

There is another flow, however that does show this breakdown. It's the "Embedded Flow" (Similar concept to the Digital Goods flow in the Express Checkout family of products).

It's meant to be displayed either in a pop-up window, or within an iframe, and it will show the breakdown.

You can see it here: After you've obtained the paykey, and made the SetPaymentOptions call, redirect the user to the following URL:

https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay?paykey=< YOURPAYKEY >

(The above is for production settings. Make sure you use the Sandbox URL if you're testing under that environment).

For more info, see page 26 
[ https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf ]